# Matplotlib crash error on mac

Tags: python-2.7, osx-lion

I can't run `matplotlib` on `python 2.7`. For example:

```
from pylab import * 
x  = arange(-10.0, 10.0, 0.1)
y = sin(x)
plot(x,y)
```

is able to run.

but

```
from pylab import *
x  = arange(-10.0, 10.0, 0.1)
y = sin(x)
plot(x,y)
show()
```

is not. The `show()` function cannot run.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the error that you get in the console?

Comment: I'm able to run this with matplotlib==1.3.1 on Mac with Python 2.7.6 on Terminal.  What versions are you running? How are you running this? (Terminal, iPython, etc)